# What's the normal duty cycle of a refrigerator compressor?

Tags: refrigerator

I recently bought a house and it came with a fridge. It's a GE model GSH25JSXSS  side by side. I think it's fairly new because the seller's agent told the seller to replace her appliances with stainless steel ones so it will show better.
Anyway, it works, keeps food cold and ice frozen, but I find the compressor is on an awful lot of the time.

I figure maybe nowadays the compressors are really low power consuming (I don't see the lights dim when the compressor starts up) so they run longer. Is this the case or is there something wrong with my fridge? I don't see any leaks in the door seam with the frame. Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: What is the temperature like in the room?  How low do you have the thermostat set on the fridge?

Comment: You could try plugging in a kill-a-watt (or similar product), to see how much energy is actually being used. You should be able to compare this to the [EnergyGuide rating](http://www.energystar.gov/index.cfm?fuseaction=refrig.search_refrigerators) to see if it's running excessively. (Hint: search for GSH25JSX*)

Comment: @gregmac, the kill-a-watt that I've used isn't designed for high amp appliances, so it may not work for a refrigerator.

Comment: @BMitch: Didn't know that. Worth checking before you buy then. The one I have (which is not an actual "Kill-a-watt") works, and in fact I had my fridge plugged in for a week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be normal.  According to the [manual](http://products.geappliances.com/MarketingObjectRetrieval/Dispatcher?RequestType=PDF&Name=49-60514-3.pdf).

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: good find, thanks, but they don't indicate much what "longer than your old fridge" but it's nice to know there's something efficient about the compressor.

Comment: @stu Too many variables involved to say exactly how much longer it will run. As long as it's not running constantly, or having trouble keeping a consistent temperature, I wouldn't worry too much about it.